# Is possible Asp.Net OData Web Api validation before deserialization?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

When I try to post `string` value to `int` property I would like to get an error

```
input.propertyName : propertyName value should be of type 'Edm.Int32'
```

but Asp.Net OData is giving an exception message

```
input : Cannot convert the literal '3a' to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'.
```

This should be a validation error, not an exception IMO.

Is there a way configuring OData to validate before type conversion? Or handling this kind of exceptions with field paths and validation types?

I am trying to achieve mapping this kind of errors with fields on my presentation and giving more suitable messages.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Model Validation in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) in Odata.

Comment: The Model Validation is not solving my situation. If client sends { SomeNumber: '' } asp.net web api returning 'cannot convert literal' message even if I applied RangeValidator on my property.